# Not display form in DetailView (Django)

Tags: python, django, forms, django-template

Я новичок в python и столкнулся с проблемой - моя форма не отображается на странице.
Я прочитал много подобных вопросов, но ничего не работает.
Я не понимаю, как именно добавить поле комментария в `DetailView` другого объекта

**urls.py**:

```py
path('test/<int:pk>/', views.DetailScenario.as_view(), name='get_scenario'),
path('test/<int:pk>/comment/', views.DetailScenario.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
```

**/views.py:**

```py
class DetailScenario(DetailView):
    template_name = 'tests/scenario.html'
    model = TestCase

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailScenario, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(scenario_public=self.object)
        return context

    def add_comment_scenario(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        scenario = TestCase.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])[0]

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.scenario_public = scenario
            comment.save()
            return redirect('tests:get_scenario', scenario.id)
        return render(request, 'scenario.html', context={'form': form, 'is_edit': True})
```

**/forms.py**

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

Шаблон:

```html
<div class="card my-4">
  <h7 class="card-header">Add comments:</h7>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Модель:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, )
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    scenario_public = models.ForeignKey(TestCase, related_name="commented_post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

По этому коду не отображается форма на странице

[image: Скрин элемента с сайта]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.